# Add font ressource on runTime

Tags: java, android, fonts, textview, runtime

I'm trying to add a font to my app dynamically. I want to change the font of every TextView of my app on runtime according to the font indicated by my server. Is there a way to download a font (ttf file or other) and use it on run time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Super cool problem, so I'm gonna give this a go and point you in the right direction since I definitely think it's possible.

First, there are a couple pieces I'm thinking of:

1. Something to download the font
2. Something to hold the active font
3. Some way to deal with it when the font isn't available (or, easier, hold off displaying anything until the font is available)
4. A custom TextView to use the active font

I'm going to leave #1 up to you, as I believe the download part was a bit off the scope of how to actually use the font and there are plenty of ways to download a file.

For #2, we could use a singleton to hold a reference to the active TypeFace (this way we're not also recreating it for every View that wants to use it):

```
public class FontHolder {
    private static FontHolder instance;
    public static FontHolder getInstance(Context context){
        if(instance == null) 
            instance = new FontHolder(context);

        return instance;
    }

    private static final String PREF_TABLE = "font_prefs"
    private static final String ACTIVE_FONT_PREF = "active_font_file";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PREF_ASSET = "fonts/default_font.ttf";

    private Context context;
    private Typeface activeTypeFace;

    protected FontHolder(Context context){
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();

        String activeFilePath = getSavedActiveFont();
        this.activeTypeFace = activeFilePath == null
                ? Typeface.createFromAssets(context.getResources().getAssets()
                : Typeface.createFromFile(new File(activeFilePath));
    }

    private String getSavedActiveFont(){
        return context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_TABLE, 0)
            .getString(ACTIVE_FONT_PREF, null);
    }

    public void setActiveFont(File activeFontFile){
        this.activeFont = Typeface.createFromFile(activeFontFile);

        context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_TABLE, 0)
            .edit()
            .putString(ACTIVE_FONT_PREF, activeFontFile.getAbsolutePath())
            .commit();
    }

    public Typeface getActiveFont(){
        return activeFont;
    }
}
```

As you can see, using that we can easily change the active font in our instance, and store a reference to the file in the preferences to persist beyond the session. If you want to add different variations (e.g. bold, italic, etc.) you could modify the template.

It also has a reference to an asset file to default the typeface to when none is currently saved.

Now we need a custom TextView to use this TypeFace:

```
public class DynamicFontTextView extends TextView {

    public DynamicFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        updateActiveFont();
    }

    public DynamicFontTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        updateActiveFont();
    }

    public DynamicFontTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        updateActiveFont();
    }

    @Override
    public void setTypeface(Typeface tf, int style) {
        // if(style == Typeface.BOLD) <-- Something for later
        super.setTypeface(FontHolder.getInstance().getActiveFont());
    }

    public void updateActiveFont(){
        super.setTypeface(FontHolder.getInstance().getActiveFont());
    }
}
```

Now, in your XML files, you can use your DynamicFontTextView with something like:

```
<com.package.DynamicFontTextView
 ....
 />
```

Now, to go back to part #3. If the font isn't available, you're going to have to download it. While it's downloading, you have 2 choices:

```
A. Prevent them from getting to a screen where the custom font would ever be used.
B. Render with a default font, and then update the Views once the font is available
```

Let's go with A in this case since it's relatively easy: just create a splash page and don't allow the user to continue until the font has downloaded.

Again, a splash page is a bit beyond the scope of this, but hopefully this should point you in the right direction on how to accomplish your task.